# ConstraintLayout issue with horizontal weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Consider following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which produces this layout which is what I want:

[image]

But if I mark B3 as gone then B1's width is set to 0 and B2 move to left. Whereas I want B2 to take B3's place and B1 to expand:

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set `android:layout_width = "0dp"` and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` for B2 and you are set to go.

EDIT: Just remove `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b3"` from B2.

Comment: But that will change the width of B2, that's not what I want. Look at the first screenshot. I want B1 to be flexible, B2 and B3 should be `wrap_content`.

Comment: just remove the `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b3"` from B2 as the B3 view is set to GONE visibility the layout confuses on what to keep this B2 view to the left of. 
Sorry, I misunderstood your question at the start.

Comment: I wanted to keep it bi-directional chain. But anyways, removing `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf ="@id/b3"` solved my issue.